# Qweb report in one page odoo 9

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

How define in .xml display data in one page (one below the other). After generate qweb in my example data is display on 4 pdf page!

Example:

```
datas = {
                 'ids': ids,
                 'model': 'my.model',
                 'form': data
                }
        return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
                'report_name': "my_module.my_report",
                'datas': datas,
            }
```

**return: [1, 2, 3, 4]**

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="report_my_document">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
          <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><t t-esc="o.name"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="o.state"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
             </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_my">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="my_module.report_my_document"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

How define foreach to display data in one pdf documen **(thead + 4 row)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each record is a row in your table, you probably want something more like this.

```
<template id="report_my_document">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
          <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><t t-esc="o.name"/></td>
                                    <td><t t-esc="o.state"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
             </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_my">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-call="my_module.report_my_document"/>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Good job, Tnx a lot of!